# Magic Packet Waking wrong computer "Wake on Lan"

Tags: wake-on-lan, magic-packet

I have 2 computers on my network that I want to be able to wake using a magic packet.  Lets call the 2 computers A and B.

Computer A will wake if I broadcast a magic packet with its mac address as expected.
Computer B will wake if I broadcast a magic packet with its mac address also.

The problem is.... when I broadcast a magic packet for computer A, computer B wakes up also.

If I broadcast a magic packet for computer B, only computer B wakes up, or turns on.

Its as if computer B wakes up anytime a magic packet is broadcasted regardless of the mac address in the magic packet.

Has anyone come across this before?  I'm stumped!

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a buggy NIC.

Answer (score 0):

After using wire shark I found the problem.  I am using a propeller based udp server to send out the magic packets. The server is sending out a magic packet for both A and B computers when I request just A.  So the problem is in my coding of the udp server.